# Should I use db.collection.distinct()?

Tags: mongodb, performance

I'm working on a ecommerce project based on MERN Stack. when a user land on my product search  page, i have to fetch list of all flavours & categories that are available for search.

i know two ways to do it (described below) & i don't know which one is better || their is a better option.

1. store all flavour and categories in an array (in other document) and update them when ever a new product with a new cat&flav added.
2. or use  db.collection.distinct() on products collection. to fetch all distinct flav and categories.

I know the 2 way is easier  than 1 , but what if i have  10,000 or 1 million  products or more.

then what is better for performance, is first one is better (faster) or it doesn't matter, like both are fine. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont go with the first option as it will make your backend code messier.

THe second option is good if the volume of the data is lesser.

Since you have data of volume 10,000 or 1 million below is the method I would suggest.

Create index on the key in question

```
db.collection.createIndex({"someKey": 1})
```

Use aggregation to fetch the unique values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$sort": {"someKey": 1},
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$someKey"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "distinctValues": {"$push": "$_id"},
        }
    },
], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

Let me know in the comments if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second way is better , because when you want to add new product you didn't need `update` and use `insert` and its more simpler than of `update`

Comment: I know the second way is easier, but you are sure this way is better in the term of performance?

Comment: I'm in the dark here, i mean i don't know how distinct algorithm works behind the scenes. Now let suppose If i have millions of products (documents) then to fetch all distinct categories "distinct" need to check all of the millions product (doc) that will take time at some point right? Even if I have only 200 different categories right? Then what should be the better way ? or I'm just overthinking it

Comment: @Divesh: yeah, you are overthinking it. Best way is to measure both options and then decide. My educated guess is that the cached/precalculated array will be faster (no work is better than no work), but do you have enough products/volume to make it worth the additional complexity?